# jQuery UI Autocomplete JSON array

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following json array:

```
partTags = [{"part":"Part1","dwg":"A"},{"part":"Part2","dwg":"B"}]
```

Which basically carries the Part Number and a corresponding Drawing Number/Letter

Prior to adding a second parameter ( "Drawing Number ") I just had the part number and I used jQuery autocomplete to search the array. What I want to do now is to Search for the part number in my first input:   `<input type="text" id="part_number">` and automatically add its corresponding Drawing Number to a second input:  `<input type="text" id="drawing_number">` upon clicking the part number.

Here is what I had:

```
$( "#part_number" ).autocomplete({
   delay: 100,
   source: partTags
});
```

How can I modify the code above to achieve this? I don't work much with jQuery so I'm quite lost when it comes to some of the API.

Here's what I have so far after fiddling a bit...

```
$( "#part_number" ).autocomplete({
     delay: 45,
    source: partTags,
    select: function(event, ui)
    {
        $(this).val(ui.item.part);
        $("input#drawing_number").val(ui.item.dwg); 
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I figured it out after looking at the API.

```
partTags = [{"label":"Part1","dwg":"A"},{"label":"Part2","dwg":"B"}]
```

I had to re-name "part" to "label"

```
$( "#part_number" ).autocomplete({
     delay: 45,
    source: partTags,
    select: function(event, ui)
    {

        $(this).val(ui.item.label);
        $(this).closest('tr').find("input[id^='drawing_number']").val(ui.item.dwg); 
        return false; // find the drawing number input on that row
    }
    }).data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function(ul, item){
        if(item.dwg!=null ||  item.dwg!='') // if the drawing is null or empty
        {
            return $( "<li></li>" ).data( "item.autocomplete", item ).append( "<a><strong>" + item.label + "</strong> - Rev " + item.dwg + "</a>" ).appendTo( ul );
        }
        else
        {
            return $( "<li></li>" ).data( "item.autocomplete", item ).append( "<a><strong>" + item.label + "</strong></a>" ).appendTo( ul );
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

I never used local string for autocomplete but the following worked.

```
    $("#part_number").autocomplete({
minLength: 0,
source: function (request, response) {
    $.post("/echo/json/", {
        json: '[{"part":"Part1","dwg":"A"},{"part":"Part2","dwg":"B"}]',
        delay: 1
    }, function (data) {
        response($.map(data, function (pn) {
            return {
                value: pn.dwg,
                label: pn.part
            };
        }));
    });
},
select: function (event, ui) {
    $('#part_number').val(ui.item.label);
    $("input#drawing_number").val(ui.item.value);
    return false;
}
});
```

Here is a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ErLQS/2/)

Comment: Thanks for that! The only thing is that if the source is from a remote location, it won't filter what you're typing... I don't know how to get that to work. I end up loading everything in a global variable when the page loads which consumes time. Ideally I would like it to get the Json from a remote file in order for the results to be live in case of change... Any ideas?

Comment: @Dimitri You're welcome. Here is [link](http://developwithstyle.com/articles/2010/05/14/jquery-ui-autocomplete-is-it-any-good/) that might be of some help to you if want to get a few tips on how to implement autocomplete for Remote Data or caching query results.

Comment: That is a great article! Thanks for sharing.

Best.